# Lagom Framework Topic Websocket Timeout connection closed with error

Tags: akka-stream, lagom

I have created a lagom Topic in my service.

`def addingsTopic(): Topic[ProcessDefinitionAdded]`

the descriptor:

```
override def descriptor: Descriptor = {
    import Service._
    named(ProductionService.TOPIC_NAME).withCalls(
      pathCall(pathProcessDef(":id"), getProcessDefinition _)
    ).withTopics(
      topic("processdef", addingsTopic _ )
        .addProperty(
          KafkaProperties.partitionKeyStrategy,
          PartitionKeyStrategy[ProcessDefinitionAdded](_.entityId.toString)
        ),
      topic("productionserviceorder", ordersTopic _)
        .addProperty(
          KafkaProperties.partitionKeyStrategy,
          PartitionKeyStrategy[OrderAddedTopic](_.entityId.toString)
        )
    ).withAutoAcl(true)
  }
```

Until here all is clear. Now I have a play webpage. I have in my controller a Websocket.

```
val k = productionService.addingsTopic().subscribe.atMostOnceSource.mapAsync(1){e ⇒
    productionService.getProcessDefinition(e.entityId).invoke().map{e ⇒
      Json.toJson(e)(ProcessDefinitionResponse.format)
    }
  }.toMat(BroadcastHub.sink(256) )(Keep.right).run().recover{
    case e ⇒ println(e)
      Json.toJson("error "+e)
  }
  val f = Flow.fromSinkAndSource(Sink.ignore,k.concat(Source.maybe))

  def fetchProcessDefinition() = WebSocket.accept[String,JsValue] { req ⇒
    f
  }
```

My javascript website use this to connect:

```
<script>
        try{
            console.log("START");
            var socket = new WebSocket("ws://localhost:9000/processdef/stream");

            socket.onopen = function(s){
                console.log("OPEN");
                console.log(s);
            };

            socket.onerror = function(error){
                console.log("ERROR: ");
                console.log(error);
            };

            socket.onmessage = function(msg){
                console.log("Message:");
                console.log(JSON.stringify(msg.data));
            };

            socket.onclose = function(closeevent){
                console.log("CLOSE:");
                console.log(closeevent);
            };

            socket.send("")
        }catch (e) {
            console.error(e);
        }
    </script>
```

I load the page on localhost after sbt runAll. It takes a time then the websockets connects (sometimes a few minutes and sometimes a few seconds). After ~ 90 seconds the console prints that the connection is closed out.
On IDE I get this error:

```
2018-10-18T10:54:16.655Z [error] akka.actor.ActorSystemImpl [sourceThread=application-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-213, akkaSource=akka.actor.ActorSystemImpl(application), sourceActorSystem=application, akkaTimestamp=10:54:16.654UTC] - Websocket handler failed with The connection closed with error: The connection was reset by peer
akka.stream.StreamTcpException: The connection closed with error: The connection was reset by peer
2018-10-18T10:54:16.674Z [error] akka.actor.ActorSystemImpl [sourceThread=application-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-231, akkaSource=akka.actor.ActorSystemImpl(application), sourceActorSystem=application, akkaTimestamp=10:54:16.674UTC] - Websocket handler failed with The connection closed with error: The connection was reset by peer
akka.stream.StreamTcpException: The connection closed with error: The connection was reset by peer
```

That is very stressful. Do I have any mistakes in my code?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: I'm not very good at German -- could you translate the errors?

Comment: Die Verbindung wurde vom Kommunikationspartner zurückgesetzt = The connection was reset by peer